# Would it be on topic if I ask questions about a specific brand?

Tags: discussion, faq, on-topic

I have some questions about Faber Castell pencils, like where they are manufactured and if there's any difference between materials used in different model numbers of pencils of the same series (for example, one was manufactured 10 years ago and another today, both are the same series, but the model number is a bit different).

**Would it be on topic to ask after a brand and its manufacturing locations and materials?**

Comment: I hope you did [some basic research](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faber-Castell)? E.g. manufacturing places will vary depending on where you buy your pens, but that’s the case for many goods.

Comment: @Stephie Yeah, I saw the same a few hours ago :D It has India's name, too. But I'm a bit curious if the quality can differ between pencils of the same series if they're manufactured in different countries. Like one has slightly better wood and graphite, and the other is a bit bad? I'm a bit skeptic because I feel the one they make in Germany is the best.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only problem with questions (and answers) about specific brands is that they can lead to biased information. If a question is asking after objective, critical (and finite) information, it probably is a good question.

Another problem that your particular question could *potentially* have, is that said information is simply not available to the public (it should be as a product, but it might not be, or be incomplete). But that is still no grounds for such a question to be off-topic.

Here are a few completely on-topic questions that are similar in nature, asking after the qualities of a specific product:

- [Crayola Air-Dry Clay Disintegrating Over the Years](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/10417/crayola-air-dry-clay-disintegrating-over-the-years)
- [Is DecoArt Standard Crafter's acrylic paint good for a concrete cockerel for outdoor use?](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/10386/is-decoart-standard-crafters-acrylic-paint-good-for-a-concrete-cockerel-for-out)
- [Paper's preservation (fixative not working)](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/9018/papers-preservation-fixative-not-working)